# Automatic follow system for PHP Facebook login user

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to make a system that follow new user's Facebook friend automatically.

When a user log in to the website with their Facebook ID, the server store their Facebook id number into the db column.

Therefore, I would like to retrieve Facebook friend id numbers and match them to current signed user's Facebook ID numbers.

here is array data from Facebook friend.

```
Array (
    [data] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [name] => James1
            [id] => 1111
        )
        [1] => Array ( 
            [name] => James2
            [id] => 2222
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [name] => James3
            [id] => 3333
        )
        [3] => Array ( 
            [name] => James4
            [id] => 4444
        )
        [4] => Array ( 
            [name] => James5
            [id] => 5555
        ) [5] => Array ( 
            [name] => James6
            [id] => 6666
        )
    )
)
```

I tried to use in_array PHP command, but didn't work.

Can you give me an idea how to make this?

Comment: Show us your code that didn't work.  I suspect you weren't looking at the elements in the sub-array.  Also, don't post personal data here!  What you've done is actually a violation of Facebook TOS.

Comment: @Brad I tried various code to match the numbers but didn't work well. I guess if I post wrong code here it will distract entire question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
foreach($yourArr['data'] as $val) {
   if($yourUserId == $val["id"]) {
      ///found
      break;
   }
}
```